# In Perl, how can I convert a binary string to an integer?

Tags: perl, string, binary

I have a four-byte string read from a binary file, which is supposed to represent an integer.
How do I dervive the integer?

Example:

```
my $s = '\xa8e2~';
my $i = stoi($s);
printf "%X", $i;  #gives "0x7e3265a8"
```

The solution in C is simply:

```
fread(&i,4,1,fp);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$i = unpack("s", $s)` may work, but it depends on signed/unsigned and byte ordering so you'll probably end up here: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html#Integers

Comment: It was in fact an unsigned long, so 'L' was what I need, but close enough!

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [`unpack` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html)

Comment: True, but part of SO is encouraging and helping people to find their own answers.